# How to use Meyer's singleton without copy constructor?

Tags: c++, singleton

This is the Meyer's singleton some people mentioned.

```
static Singleton& getinstance()
{
     static Singleton s_obj;
     return s_obj;
}
```

But how user use this getinstace() API?

If I use it this way.

```
Singleton myobj = getinstance();
```

I will actually make a copy of `s_obj` right?
So I have 2 instances `myobj` and `s_obj` now, which violate the purpose of a singleton.

Can anybody explain how to correctly understand Meyer's singleton?

Comment: Did you try deleting your singleton's copy constructor and assignment operator?

Comment: Yes you are right. I should delete it. And that's the reason I got confused by Meyer singleton. How to use it without copy constructor??
  
And thanks to Ayxan, I think I got the answer. 
"auto& ref = Singleton::instance();" will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is, you make the copy constructor, the move constructor, the copy assignment operator, the move assignment operator deleted and then you make the usable constructors private, so no one else can copy it:

```
class Singleton
{
public:
  Singleton(Singleton const&) = delete;
  Singleton(Singleton&&) = delete;
  Singleton& operator=(Singleton const&) = delete;
  Singleton& operator=(Singleton&&) = delete;

  static auto& instance()
  {
    static Singleton obj;
    return obj;
  }

private:
  Singleton() { /* ... */ }
};

int
main()
{
  auto& ref = Singleton::instance(); // OK
  auto copy = Singleton::instance(); // Won't compile
}
```